# iPhone sdk : How to identify type of ZbarSymbol

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, zbar

I want to know the type of data returned by Zbar sdk. I have multiple QR codes to scan and want to know whether returned data are hyperlink,plain text or number.

I have implemented following code to check is link or not. But i want to check for multiple results.

```
- (void) readerView: (ZBarReaderView*) view
     didReadSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet*) syms
          fromImage: (UIImage*) img
{
//    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

    // do something useful with results

    ZBarSymbol *symbol;
    for(symbol in syms)
        break;

     NSString *scannedText = symbol.data;


    if([scannedText hasPrefix:@"http"]) {
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check the [zbarsymbol](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ZBarSymbol.html) for detail.